# Problemas con fichero javascript que no llega a ser atendido por HttpModule

Tags: asp.net, .net, aplicación-web, iis, navegador-web

Se trata de un HttpModule instalado en la aplicación web que gestiona las peticiones realizadas sobre distintos ficheros (*.css, *.js, *.aspx, *.ashx).

Cada vez que se pide una página de la aplicación por primera vez, el navegador cliente (Chrome, Firefox, IE, etc) pide y lee cada uno de los documentos que componen la página (hojas de estilos, javascript, AJAX, etc) para interpretarlos. Las veces consecutivas lee los ficheros de recursos desde su caché.

El problema surge cuando refrescamos la página con "Ctrl + F5" y esperamos que la petición vuelva a llegar al IIS y sea el HttpModule el que se encargue de su tratamiento, y no es así, **no llega la petición al HttpModule con lo cual el IIS termina sirviendo la versión original del fichero sin el tratamiento de filtro**.

Entiendo que el fichero es leído desde alguna caché distinta a la del navegador, y no es la aplicación web.

La instalación del HttpModule la realizo en el web.config de la aplicación:

```
<system.webServer>
    <!-- Sección para los módulos con canalización integrada (IIS 7) -->
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <remove name="ServiceModel" />
      <add name="MiHttpModule" type="MiNamespace.MiHttpModule, MiNamespace" preCondition="" />
    </modules>    
</system.webServer>
```

Edito: De la instalación del Module en el web.config, he quitado preCondition="managedHandler", ya que los recursos *.css y *.js no son manejados por el gestor del IIS. ([INFO](https://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/introduction-to-iis/iis-modules-overview#Precondition))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He encontrado que las peticiones si llegaban al httpModule, pero no eran tratadas correctamente debido a un cambio en la codificación de los ficheros.
La solución la he encontrado en [este hilo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13338332/response-filter-breaks-encoding-randomly#13848536)